# does any one know how to play video in video using VideoView

Tags: android, video

```
    File f = new File("/sdcard/Sample.3gp");
    byte[] videoUp=new byte[576600];  
    videoUp = IOUtils.toByteArray( new FileInputStream(f));
```

// I want to play video after i convert it into bytes
nothning makes it to play when i convert and put to videoview.

Comment: why you want to convert it to bytearray

Comment: i'm making an app where i'm sending and receiving video... i'm sending using ftp, i have created service to fetch that video and send to android mobile, so i'm converting it to bytes and receiving bytes, storing in sdcard and then playing video

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView01);
 MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
 mediaController.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
 videoView.setVideoPath(path);   
 videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
 videoView.requestFocus();
 videoView.start();
 mediaController.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can directly play video from sdcard as,

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
videoView.setVideoPath("/sdcard/Sample.3gp");    
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
videoView.requestFocus();
videoView.start();
```

You can use MediaController if you want to control any player options.